Stealing funds with batchTransferWithAuthorization(0xcccbb34c) and safeTransferFrom(0x42842e0e)
I had funds stolen from the Arbitrum and Ethereum network the other day using batchTransferWithAuthorization(0xcccbb34c) and safeTransferFrom(0x42842e0e).
Is it enough to do a revoke so that the hacker can no longer transfer my funds?

Hi, I think this needs clarity as to what happened ideally with a tx hash, but it sounds it like it was bad approval and a revoke of the bad actors allowance should be enough.
